# Why this compilation difference?

Tags: c#, compilation, compiler-errors, boolean

Don't know what to title it, but here's what I have.

[image]

As you can see I have following lines of code where 1st and 2nd lines are okay but third line is causing error.

Can someone explain why? I have a feeling that it might be because `(s is PaymentSchdule)` needs to be evaluated at runtime, is that the reason?

Comment: You have an extra pair of `()` in sceenshot `(s is PaymentSchdule())`. The text you posted would be correct: `(s is PaymentSchedule)`.

Comment: What Is PaymentSchedule ? A class or a function which returns a type??

Comment: And do you mean `s as PaymentSchdule`? `s is PaymentSchdule` will return a bool so you will get somthing like "Payment schedule: true Code: ..."

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.  To check if something is of a specified type:

```
s is PaymentSchedule
```

Not

```
s is PaymentSchedule()
```

Resulting in you changing you code to:

```
Console.WriteLine("PaymentSchedule: " + (s is PaymentSchedule).ToString() + "Code: " + s.GetHashCode());
```

I'd be tempted to write it like this for better readability, though:

```
Console.WriteLine("PaymentSchedule: {0} Code: {1}", s is PaymentSchedule, s.GetHashCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written `PaymentSchedule()`. It should be `PaymentSchedule`